# Downgrade and disable play store updates

Tags: google-play-store, downgrade

I have a rooted OP3 on Android 7.1.1 with Play Store v. 8.2.38. I have tried uninstalling updates from apps manager(which reverts it to 7.9 the version I want to keep) but it updates Play store as soon as I open it afterwards. I can't keep my phone offline and I need app updates but not the play store itself. I want to keep Play Store at 7.9 or 8.0. How Do I go about doing that? All the related posts here are either outdated or not working

Answer (score 1):

[Freedom](https://in-appstore.com/android/) has a handy feature:

[image: Screenshot]

It works for me (OnePlus 5, 7.1.1 rooted)

Comment: I see what you did there! ;)

Comment: Why does people want to stay on older version of play store I get it for some apps but play store?

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје Freedom, does not support Play Store 8+, and it's the primary reason why I stay at 7.9.

Comment: @PranjalJain I didn't quite understand you :(

Comment: @iBug Hey man, I tried this, but it doesn't stay at 7.9 for long, it reverts to 8 sooner or later, I think it's maybe because Freedom doesn't remain in background all the time?

Comment: Works for me with no faults. I have a OnePlus 5 with rooted stock 7.1.1 which is also extremely similar to yours, so is there anything wrong?